# Learning cryptography

Tags: encryption

I am new to cryptography but I want to learn about it. I would like to get from you a list (possibly ordered) of "must have and read" book titles.

Best regards

Comment: The answer is depends on the your background. Jean-Philippe Aumasson's [Serious Cryptography](https://www.amazon.com/Serious-Cryptography-Practical-Introduction-Encryption/dp/1593278268) might be a good start. Then Lindell&Katz book. Your question is specific to you and better to be asked in chat.

Comment: https://toc.cryptobook.us/